# In PHP, each character in decompressed gz string is followed by ^@, why?

Tags: c#, php, string, gzip, sharpziplib

I'm sending over a gzipped string from C# (using SharpZipLib) to PHP where I decompress with readgzfile. This works, however each character in the string is followed by two strange characters (using vim in the console those are displayed as `^@`). I also tried with gzopen/gzread but with the same results.

When I clean the non-ASCII characters from the string with `$clean= preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $string);` the $clean string is identical to the one in C#.

While this works, I would like to know what is happening and why so I can make sure this will always work or come up with a better solution.

Comment: Was your source string in UCS2 or UTF-16 perhaps?

Comment: I'm not applying or converting to a specific encoding. Maybe I should though, what encoding should I then use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the string is created on Windows, it's likely that some multibyte encoding is being used.

You can verify this yourself by using `bin2hex($string)` and check the hexadecimal representation instead of relying on vim.

If either `UTF-16` or `UCS2` are being used, you can convert them like so:

```
// iconv($from, $to, $str)
$clean = iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $string);
```

Comment: That did the trick, so I guess it uses one of those two. Thanks.